# Common Design for Console and GUI

Tags: c++, oop, design-patterns, language-agnostic

I am designing a little game for my own fun's and training's sake. The real identity of the game being quite irrelevant for my actual question, suppose it's the [Mastermind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mastermind_%28board_game%29) game (which it actually is :)

My real goal here is to have an interface `IPlayer` which will be used for any player: computer or human, console or gui, local or network. I am also intending to have a GameController, which will deal with just two `IPlayer`s.

the IPlayer interface would look something like this:

```
class IPlayer
{
public:
    //dtor
    virtual ~IPlayer()
    {
    }
    //call this function before the game starts. In subclasses,
    //the overriders can, for example, generate and store the combination.
    virtual void PrepareForNewGame() = 0;
    //make the current guess
    virtual Combination MakeAGuess() = 0;
    //return false if lie is detected.
    virtual bool ProcessResult(Combination const &, Result const &) = 0;
    //Answer to opponent's guess
    virtual Result AnswerToOpponentsGuess(Combination const&) = 0;
};
```

The GameController class would do something like this:

```
IPlayer* pPlayer1 = PlayerFactory::CreateHumanPlayer();
IPlayer* pPlayer1 = PlayerFactory::CreateCPUPlayer();

pPlayer1->PrepareForNewGame();
pPlayer2->PrepareForNewGame();

while(no_winner)
{
   Guess g = pPlayer1->MakeAguess();
   Result r = pPlayer2->AnswerToOpponentsGuess(g);
   bool player2HasLied = ! pPlayer1->ProcessResult(g, r);
   etc. 
   etc.
}
```

By this design, I am willing to make GameController class immutable, that is, I stuff the just game rules in it, and nothing else, so since the game itself is established, this class shouldn't change. For a console game this design would work perfectly. I would have `HumanPlayer`, which in its `MakeAGuess` method would read a `Combination` from the standard input, and a `CPUPlayer`, which would somehow randomly generate it etc.

Now here's my problem: The `IPlayer` interface, along with the `GameController` class, are synchronous in their nature. I can't imagine how I would implement the GUI variant of the game with the same `GameController` when the `MakeAGuess` method of `GUIHumanPlayer` would have to wait for, for example, some mouse movements and clicks. Of course, I could launch a new thread which would wait for user input, while the main thread would block, so as to imitate synchronous IO, but somehow this idea disgusts me. Or, alternatively, I could design both the controller and player to be asynchronous. In this case, for a console game, I would have to imitate asynchronousness, which seems easier than the first version.

Would you kindly comment on my design and my concerns about choosing synchronous or asynchronous design? Also, I am feeling that I put more responsibility on the player class than GameController class. Etc, etc.

Thank you very much in advance.

P.S. I don't like the title of my question. Feel free to edit it :)

Comment: I do like the title :-)

Comment: I removed the C# tag, as there is no C# anywhere near this question.

Comment: Since language is irrelevant, I am hoping to get C# experts' opinion as well

Comment: Then put a language-agnostic tag on it, not specific language tags. The language tags are there for questions specific to a language. Why not just tag it with every OOP language under the sun?

Comment: As a general rule, tagging in hopes of attracting a larger audience is discouraged. Tagging is for categorizing the question.

Comment: I may be little naive , how would you create object for the Abstract class ?? .

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Instead of using return values of the various `IPlayer` methods, consider introducing an observer class for `IPlayer` objects, like this:

```
class IPlayerObserver
{
public:
  virtual ~IPlayerObserver() { }
  virtual void guessMade( Combination c ) = 0;
  // ...
};

class IPlayer
{
public:
  virtual ~IPlayer() { }
  virtual void setObserver( IPlayerObserver *observer ) = 0;
  // ...
};
```

The methods of `IPlayer` should then call the appropriate methods of an installed `IPlayerObserver` instead of returning a value, as in:

```
void HumanPlayer::makeAGuess() {
  // get input from human
  Combination c;
  c = ...;
  m_observer->guessMade( c );
}
```

Your GameController class could then implement `IPlayerObserver` so that it gets notified whenever a player did something interesting, like - making a guess.

With this design, it's perfectly fine if all the `IPlayer` methods are asynchronous. In fact, it's to be expected - they all return `void`!. Your game controller calls `makeAGuess` on the active player (this might compute the result immediately, or it might do some network IO for multiplayer games, or it would wait for the GUI to do something) and whenever the player did his choice, the game controller can rest assured that the `guessMade` method will be called. Furthemore, the player objects still don't know anything about the game controller. They are just dealing with an opaque 'IPlayerObserver' interface.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing making this different for the GUI as compared to the console is that your GUI is event driven. Those events take place on the GUI thread, and therefore, if you host the Game code on the GUI thread, you have a problem: Your call to have the player make a move blocks the GUI thread, and this means you can't get any events until that call returns. [EDIT: Inserted the following sentence.] But the call can't return until it gets the event. So you're deadlocked.

That problem would go away if you simply host the game code on another thread. You'd still need to synchronize the threads, so MakeAGuess() doesn't return until ready, but it's certainly doable.

If you want to keep everything single-threaded you may want to consider a different model. Game could notify Players it's their turn with an event but leave it to players to initiate operations on the Game.